# Find music videos in bulk

Tags: windows-7, video, mp3, music, youtube

I have a fairly large MP3 collection, that I would like to upgrade to a music video collection.  Basically what I want to do is go through all my songs and find matching music videos.  I plan on doing final approval of the video myself, so no auto-replacing of files.  I know some music is available on artists' official channels on YouTube or other similar sites.

Is there an easy way for the computer to scan my music collection and find music videos matching my metadata?  Or am I doomed to do this by hand?

EDIT:  I am using Windows 7.

Comment: You could write a script, which extracts the mp3 tags like artist and song title for each song and looks it up on Youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're a Spotify user, you could try publishing a playlist with all songs (should work even with local MP3 files) and then use http://www.utubify.com/ to create a corresponding Youtube playlist.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like Spotify is not available to me here in Canada.

Comment: Doesn't help me in Canada (yet), but it looks like a good site for those who are able to use it.  Gave you the bounty, but still hoping for something more widely available.

Comment: You could try a US (or EU) based VPN or tunneling service to access Spotify temporarily to solve this particular issue.